# Dynamically load and assign ids to array elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an array and I want to display the elements on to the webpage and dynamically assign Ids to the array elements(ids that can be accessed through getElementById). I am new to javascript and jquery.
Help needed.

```js
function register() {
  var ids = ['name', 'lname', 'email', 'password', 'cpassword'];
  var printThis = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    printThis += "<br>" + ids[i];
  }
  return printThis; // <-- to be printed to the div
}

document.getElementById('ids').innerHTML = register();
```

```html
<div id="ids"></div>
```

Comment: What exactly should the output look like? Given that you're already concatenating the string you just need to wrap the `ids[i]` value in whatever tag you need.

Comment: I expect that i can get element of each id from the webpage for further work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

For setting Id:

> var setIds= $('#mydiv').attr('id');
>
> var setIds= '#mydiv'+i

```js
function register() {
  var ids = ['name', 'lname', 'email', 'password', 'cpassword'];
  var printThis = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    printThis += "<br>" + ids[i];
    var setIds= $('#mydiv').attr('id');
    var setIds= '#mydiv'+i
  }
  return printThis; // <-- to be printed to the div
}

document.getElementById('ids').innerHTML = register();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ids"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you but I need more help. I want to access those ids on the html page.